# Access a method from razor file in Blazor Server

Tags: c#, razor, blazor

I have a void function defined in CrackWidth.cs file

```
namespace Concrete.CrackWidth.Pages
{
  public partial class CrackWidth
    {
        private void UpdateMainDwg()
         {
          }
    }
}
```

I would like to call that method when textfield is changed to update the graphics using MudTextField TextChanged function in Layout2.razor file:

```
<MudTextField @bind-Value="InputModel.fyk" 
        Validation="@(InputValidator.ValidateValue)"
        For="@(() => InputModel.fyk)" 
        TextChanged="UpdateInputSVG.UpdateMainDwg"
        Immediate="true" 
        Label="Rebar tensile strength [N/mm^2]" 
        Placeholder="Tensile strength in N/mm^2" />

@code {
    [Parameter]
    public Ec2InputModel InputModel { get; set; }

    [Parameter]
    public Ec2InputValidator InputValidator { get; set; }

    [Parameter]
    public CrackWidth.Pages.CrackWidth UpdateInputSVG { get; set; }

}
```

However when I try to load the view I got the error:

```
System.ArgumentException: Delegate to an instance method cannot have null 'this'.
         at System.MulticastDelegate.ThrowNullThisInDelegateToInstance()
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like the expression `UpdateInputSVG.UpdateMainDwg` is being interpreted as `UpdateInputSvg.GetType().GetMethod("UpdateMainDwg")`, without any reference to the instance it came from (a little bit unintuitive).

The `EventCallback<T>` class used in Blazor is not exactly the same as `Action<T>`. You have to be a bit more explicit when you bind than you would with a plain `Action<T>`. In this case, you need to define a lambda with parameters that match:

```
TextChanged=@((value) => UpdateInputSVG.UpdateMainDwg())
```

Comment: Do I need to define (value) in razor? I'm getting error with "System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object."

Comment: 'value' is a string parameter provided by the `MudTextField`, containing the new value of the field. If you're getting a null reference exception, it's probably because `UpdateInputSVG` is null